# Spring java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I am using Tomcat 7.0.67, Spring 4.2.0. I am **not** using Spring-JPA, Hibernate or JPA, but when I attempt to launch my Spring application it fails with this error saying the `javax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory` class is not found:

```
23:39:43.836 ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader[] - Context initialization failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:606) ~[spring-core-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:518) ~[spring-core-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:504) ~[spring-core-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:241) ~[spring-beans-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1069) ~[spring-beans-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1042) ~[spring-beans-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305) ~[spring-beans-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301) ~[spring-beans-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196) ~[spring-beans-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834) ~[spring-context-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) ~[spring-context-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446) ~[spring-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328) ~[spring-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5077) [catalina.jar:7.0.67]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5591) [catalina.jar:7.0.67]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.67]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1574) [catalina.jar:7.0.67]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564) [catalina.jar:7.0.67]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_66]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
```

I tried adding the below to my pom.xml to include the persistence jar, but it did not make a difference.

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId> 
    <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId> 
    <version>1.0.2</version> 
</dependency>
```

This is the output of `mvn dependency:tree`: https://gist.github.com/eytanbiala/492d9af46f8990917e45

Comment: Probably you've used spring-jpa, you may need either hibernate or eclipselink. is a maven project?

Comment: please provide the output of mvn dependency:tree ?

Comment: I added a gist with the output of mvn dependency:tree

Comment: The tree is missing in your gist. Please post the full output of the command.

Comment: Sorry, I ran it at the parent pom. I updated the link with the output from running mvn dependency:tree in the main project.

Comment: as you can see yourself, there is no jpa provider and no persistence-api in your dependencies

Comment: Correct - I am not depending on JPA or persistence-api, so why is it looking for this class at all?

Answer (score 0):

please copy your hibernate-jpa jar file tomcat lib folder manually.

Comment: This works, but why? It doesn't seem like it should be necessary.